# BigDecimal.ZERO vs. new BigDecimal(0). Which to use and why?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I was wondering if these two are the same. Can anyone verify? (I am trying to replace the 1st with the 2nd)

```
BigDecimal totalCurrentSales = new BigDecimal(0);
```

and

```
BigDecimal totalCurrentSales = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

The reason I ask is that it is improper to declare it the first way since you are not supposed to create instances of already existing `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal (ZERO, ONE, TEN)`. So I was wondering if I could say it the second way and it still be considered creating an instance. Instead of me having to create a variable `zero` or something that is equal to `BigDecimal.ZERO`. Or are there any other ways?

I tried

```
BigDecimal totalCurrentSales = new BigDecimal(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

but eclipse wasn't too happy.

Comment: Yes, I do. Just looking for a solution

Comment: If you really understand these concepts, then you may already know the solution: use the latter `BigDecimal totalCurrentSales = BigDecimal.ZERO;`.

Comment: Alrighty then, was just making sure I could do that since I still needed a new instance, but trying to get rid of the `0`

Comment: BigDecimal is an immutable class. Its value will never change. So don't create a new instance of BigDecimal with the value 0. Just use the existing one. `new BigDecimal(BigDecimal.ZERO)` doesn't make any sense. It would be like writing `new String("string")`.

Comment: `BigDecimal.ZERO` is **not a new instance**. It's a reference to an existing instance.

Comment: well then help me out. I clearly don't understand the four of you then.. I need a new instance, but not with it being equal to the integer value of `0` since `BigInteger.ZERO` already exists.

Comment: Why do you need a _new_ instance? @dusky has already clarified that `BigDecimal` is immutable.

Comment: so then what i said originally was correct? `BigDecimal totalCurrentSales = BigDecimal.ZERO;` and your saying that since it's immutable there is no point to even say `new`?

Comment: A line of code is not correct or incorrect (without context). The two lines of code are absolutely not the same. That second line of code also doesn't create a new instance. If you want to have a reference to a `BigDecimal` with conceptual value `0`, then, yes, use `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Comment: @erp You don't have to create a new instance here since there is already one (BigDecimal.ZERO). BigDecimal.ZERO will never ever change. It will always have to value 0.

Comment: Mockers be warned...  BigDecimal.ZERO delegates to `private static final zeroThroughTen` so it be `null` if you're testing with mockito.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Mathematically, they're the same. Plus, since BigDecimals are immutable, you don't need to worry about creating new instances to do new calculations. As soon as you perform some operation on your `totalCurrentSales` instance, you'll actually be creating a new BigDecimal and reassigning the `totalCurrentSales` reference to the new value.

From a instantiation perspective, they're not necessarily exactly the same. In the OpenJDK 6b14 implementation, for example, `BigDecimal.ZERO` is created by invoking the private `new BigDecimal(BigInteger, long, int)` constructor with values `BigInteger.ZERO`, `0`, and `0`.

From a code quality perspective, using `BigDecimal.ZERO` is preferable to `new BigDecimal(0)` as you avoid the extra instantiation and having a literal in your code.

Comment: That last segment of what you said was really what i was looking for all along. The animosity in here off the charts. Thanks for your response. A Clear and concise answer. +1

Comment: The use of different constructors leads to `BigDecimal.ZERO` being 'inflated' and `new BigDecimal(0)` using a compact representation of the number internally. That might affect performance.

Comment: I only needed to know the solution as it came up in a Sonar error. I know performance wise it was negligible but just wanted to get it in the preferred state, as that's what sonar is for int he first place.

Answer (score 13):

BigDecimal doesn't have a constructor that takes a BigDecimal as an argument, so that explains why Eclipse would not be happy with that.

BigDecimal is immutable, which means once you create an object its state never changes.

Also BigDecimal's equals and hashcode methods are overridden to go by value, as opposed to Object's default implementation, which compares references. So there is no difference between BigDecimal.ZERO and new BigDecimal("0") from the point of view of how they are used, except that creating a new instance is more work for the JVM (and will generate more garbage when you don't need that object any more).

BigDecimal's being immutable and value-based means what specific reference is used won't matter to the code using the BigDecimal.

Because BigDecimal.ZERO is already created for you and comparisions between BigDecimals are by value, it makes sense to minimize the number of values you use so that your programs create less garbage. That's why you're getting encouraged to use BigDecimal.ZERO.

Comment: I was intending to use `BigDecimal.ZERO;` in the first place, I was just trying to understand all of the back and forth in the comments on the op. Thanks for your response tho. I would have checked it but I saw the other one first. +1 for being nice tho :)